# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFSet' (0x109b56408) to 'NSArray' Swift 4

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to get an array of location objects from the notification.userInfo inserted and deleted values and update map annotation accordingly. It will not allow me to cast it to a type `[Location]`.

I get the following error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFSet' (0x109b56408) to 'NSArray'

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! {
    didSet {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: managedObjectContext, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            if self.isViewLoaded {
                if let dictionary = notification.userInfo {
                    print(dictionary["inserted"])

                    if let inserted = dictionary["inserted"]{
                        var location = [Location]()
                        location = inserted as! [Location]
                    }

                    if let deleted = dictionary["deleted"] {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not an array, it's a set. And use proper keys to access the data.

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! {
    didSet {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: managedObjectContext, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            if self.isViewLoaded {
                if let dictionary = notification.userInfo {
                    print(dictionary[NSInsertedObjectsKey])

                    if let inserted = dictionary[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<Location> {
                        var location = Array(inserted)
                    }

                    if let deleted = dictionary[NSDeletedObjectsKey] {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I had no idea about the proper keys.